# Visual basic 6 remove and add spaces in string

Tags: vb6

I want to remove and insert spaces after every byte in a hex string.

E.g.: if the hex string is

```
str = "0F0D3E"
```

then I want to insert spaces after every byte to obtain

```
str = "0F 0D 3E"
```

and also the reverse (remove spaces from the string so the string becomes "0F0D3E" again).

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and naïve approach would be:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sSrc As String
    Dim sTgt As String

    sSrc = "0F0D3E"

    sTgt = SpaceIt(sSrc)
    Debug.Print sTgt

    sSrc = UnspaceIt(sTgt)
    Debug.Print sSrc

End Sub

Private Function SpaceIt(sSrc As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim asSrc() As String

    ReDim asSrc(0 To Len(sSrc) \ 2 - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To Len(sSrc) - 1 Step 2
        asSrc(i \ 2) = Mid$(sSrc, i + 1, 2)
    Next i
    SpaceIt = Join(asSrc, " ")
End Function

Private Function UnspaceIt(sSrc As String) As String
    UnspaceIt = Replace(sSrc, " ", "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can harness the power of the `Mid$` statement and the `Mid$` function and a little arithmetic to write a function to do this pretty flexibly and efficiently:

```
Private Function Spacify( _
    ByVal Text As String, _
    ByVal StrideIn As Long, _
    ByVal StrideOut As Long, _
    Optional ByVal RTrim As Boolean) As String

    Dim OutLen As Long
    Dim CopyLen As Long
    Dim OutPos As Long
    Dim InPos As Long

    If StrideIn <= StrideOut Then
        OutLen = (Len(Text) \ StrideIn) * StrideOut
        If RTrim Then OutLen = OutLen - (StrideOut - StrideIn)
        CopyLen = StrideIn
    Else
        OutLen = ((Len(Text) + (StrideIn - StrideOut)) \ StrideIn) * StrideOut
        CopyLen = StrideOut
    End If
    Spacify = Space$(OutLen)
    OutPos = 1
    For InPos = 1 To Len(Text) Step StrideIn
        Mid$(Spacify, OutPos) = Mid$(Text, InPos, CopyLen)
        OutPos = OutPos + StrideOut
    Next
End Function
```

Example:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim S As String

    S = "0f030d"
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    S = Spacify(S, 2, 3)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    S = Spacify(S, 3, 2)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    S = Spacify(S, 2, 3, True)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"; " trimmed"
    S = Spacify(S, 3, 2)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    Debug.Print

    S = "abc"
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    S = Spacify(S, 1, 2)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    S = Spacify(S, 2, 1)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    S = Spacify(S, 1, 2, True)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"; " trimmed"
    S = Spacify(S, 2, 1)
    Debug.Print """"; S; """"
    Stop
End Sub
```

Result:

```
"0f030d"
"0f 03 0d "
"0f030d"
"0f 03 0d" trimmed
"0f030d"

"abc"
"a b c "
"abc"
"a b c" trimmed
"abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim str As String
    Dim newstr As String

    str = "0F0D3E"

    newstr = AddSpaces(str)

    str = Replace(newstr, " ", "")

End Sub

Private Function AddSpaces(s As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(s) Step 2
        AddSpaces = AddSpaces & Mid$(s, i, 2) & " "
    Next

    AddSpaces = Trim(AddSpaces)

End Function
```

Comment: One should avoid repeated concatenations in VB6, though, for they are incredibly expensive. See Matthew Curland, Advanced Visual Basic 6. http://www.powervb.com/, chapter 14.

Comment: Using `Join()` and `Replace()` aren't exactly speed demons either, though not as bad as heavy concatenation of small Strings.